# Finding min and max between several integers

Tags: c

Seeing the solution to this online on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200031/3185410  I tried to come up with another solution by setting max to -infinity and min to +infinity. 
 The code here by @haccks works pretty fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int num, max, min;

printf ("Enter four numbers: ");
scanf ("%d", &num);
max = min = num;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{ 
    scanf ("%d", &num);
    if (max < num)
        max = num;
    else if (min > num)
        min = num;
}

printf ("\n%d %d", max, min);
return 0;
}
```

Here's the one I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
void main()
{
int max,min,num,i;
min=INT_MAX;
max=INT_MIN;
for (i=0;i<=3;)
{
    i++;
    printf("Enter number %d : ",i);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if (num>max) max=num;
    else if (num<min) min=num;
}
printf("max is %d and min is %d",max,min);
}
```

What am I doing wrong with that?

Comment: INT_MAX is the maximum value that you can store in an int so num cannot ever be more than INT_MAX and therefore if (num>max) is pointless.  Ditto for min.

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: @jarmod The code says `max=INT_MIN;` not `max=INT_MAX;`

Comment: You don't understand. 
max=INT_MIN
if num>max that means if num>INT_MIN.

Comment: the only problem I can see is that you have coupled your solution to int,if you like to change the numbers type to say long long you would have some more work to do

Comment: @Notlikethat Trying numbers 5, 6, 7, and 8 the max is 8 and the min is like 27474727273723... haha and it's NotLikeThat

Comment: @Nabla Oops, I was not paying attention!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the users input 5 then 6 you have :

for 5 :
5>-inf => max = 5

for 6 :
6>5 => max = 6
but then min has become 5 and yet it is still INT_MAX.

If you put `if` instead of `else if`, you loose in performance but have the right output I think (I cannot test right now).

Comment: Changed 'ELSE IF' with 'IF' it works! Pretty weird! Can anyone explain why?

Comment: In the example I gave, instead of just setting the max at 5, it sets max at 5 and the min at five.

Comment: @user3185410 The `else` means that whenever you have a new `max`, you set that and skip checking `min`. If this always happens, `min` never gets set.

Comment: @user3185410; *Can anyone explain why? *: To check the condition `num<min` and execute the statement `min=num;`.

Answer (score 0):

Set first input as min and max value. And then add logic you wrote. Here you had 2 lines of extra code but you don't have to sacrifice performance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
void main()
{
int max,min,num,i=0;
min=INT_MAX;
max=INT_MIN;
printf("Enter number %d : ",i+1);
scanf("%d",&num);
min=num;
max=num;
for (i=1;i<=3;)
{
    i++;
    printf("Enter number %d : ",i);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if (num>max) max=num;
    else if (num<min) min=num;
}
printf("max is %d and min is %d",max,min);
}
```