# Using only 4 'if' statements - Find Largest and Smallest of 4 integers

Tags: c, if-statement

I have been going through some basic exercises from a recommended beginner's book: [C Programming: A Modern Approach (2nd Edition)](http://knking.com/books/c2/index.html)

The question states: Use as few if statements as possible to determine the largest and smallest of four numbers entered by the user. **Four if statements are sufficient.** -- Since this question was asked before loops, arrays and functions were covered in the book, I am assuming that these should not be used.

Also, I know there was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199473/biggest-and-smallest-of-four-integers-no-arrays-no-functions-fewest-if-stat) to this one, however none meet the requirements of what I am trying to achieve.

1. Using **only 4** `if` statements
2. No for-loops.

The first thing that came to my mind was using the logical `or` operator however as shown below, eight `if` statements were used. Also this method is very long and not efficient:

```
    int a, b, c, d;

printf("Enter 4 intgeres to find largest and smallest: ");
scanf_s("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

if (a > b && a > c && a > d)
    printf("Largest: %d\n", a);
if (b > a && b > c && b > d)
    printf("Largest: %d\n", b);
if (c > a && c > b && c > d)
    printf("Largest: %d\n", c);
if (d > a && d > a && d > c)
    printf("Largest: %d\n", d);

if (a < b && a < c && a < d)
    printf("Smallest: %d\n", a);
if (b < a && b < c && b < d)
    printf("Smallest: %d\n", b);
if (c < a && c < b && c < d)
    printf("Smallest: %d\n", c);
if (d < a && d < a && d < c)
    printf("Smallest: %d\n", d);

return 0;
```

Next, I proceeded to the following code which would be a better solution:

```
    int a, b, c, d;

printf("Enter 4 intgeres to find largest and smallest: ");
scanf_s("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

int max = a, min = a;

if (b > max) 
    max = b;
else if (b < min) 
    min = b;
if (c > max) 
    max = c;
else if (c < min) 
    min = c;
if (d > max) 
    max = d;
else if (d < min) 
    min = d;

printf("max: %d min : %d\n", max, min);

return 0;
```

However, still not meeting the requirement of using 4 `if` statements. I was wondering if I could shorten my code even further. Please excuse the basic nature of this question. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, one can do that with zero `if`s, and even without `? :`, using only `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of using conditional expressions would solve this with `zero` if s. However the requirement states that I use `if` statements to achieve the result. (4 would be sufficient)

Comment: Only `if`, so no else or else if?

Comment: While I don't know if it helps (I haven't really given it much through) but if `a > b && b > c` then it follows that `a > c`.

Comment: @Stefan, `else if` can be used however, correct me if I am mistaken, an `else if` is also considered to be an if statement. Thus, in my last solution I am using 6 if statements.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes that would be the case in your example. However, I am using 4 integers, thus, the fourth integer `d` should also be utilised. This would still require me to use more than 4 `if` statements from what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should work.

It computes `max1 = max(a, b)` and `max2 = max(c, d)`, as well as `min1 = min(a, b)` and `min2 = min(c, d)`, using the first 2 `if`s.

Then the maximum is equal to `max(max(a, b), max(c, d)) = max(max1, max2)`. (The 3rd `if`.)

And the minimum is equal to `min(min(a, b), min(c, d)) = min(min1, min2)`. (The 4th `if`.)

```
int a, b, c, d;

// ...

int min, max, max1, max2, min1, min2;

if (a > b) // 1
{
    max1 = a;
    min1 = b;
}
else
{
    max1 = b;
    min1 = a;
}

if (c > d) // 2
{
    max2 = c;
    min2 = d;
}
else
{
    max2 = d;
    min2 = c;
}

if (max1 > max2) // 3
    max = max1;
else
    max = max2;

if (min1 < min2) // 4
    min = min1;
else
    min = min2;
```

## Bonus

Zero `if`s.

```
int a, b, c, d;

// ...

int min = a, max = a;
b < min && (min = b);
c < min && (min = c);
d < min && (min = d);
b > max && (max = b);
c > max && (max = c);
d > max && (max = d);
```

Comment: This exercise is setting the reader up for divide and conquer sorting techniques like quicksort. The "zero ifs" is cheating, `cond && expression` is an `if`. The problem would probably be better expressed as "using only 4 comparisons".

Comment: Is this solution considered to be more efficient than the second one i proposed since it has less if statements?

Comment: @Rizzo: Yes, HolyBlackCat's first example is more efficient that your proposed ones. Local temporary variables are "cheap"; the compiler can often optimize them away (i.e., only keep them in registers). The [Divide and conquer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) wikipedia page may shed light on the idea of splitting the problem like this. Splitting the problem up, and drawing [decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_trees), is a very useful design technique you could consider learning, for solving problems in general.

Answer (score 6):

We can use divide n conquer approach to solve this problem.

Imagine our input = [a, b, c, d]

We want to find answer from [a,b] and [c,d]

Then merge the final solution to find the answer.

```
if(a > b) swap(&a,&b); // solve [a,b]
if(c > d) swap(&c,&d); // solve [c,d]
if(a > c) swap(&a,&c); // find minimum from [a,b] and [c,d]
if(d > b) swap(&b,&d); // find maximum from [a,b] and [c,d]

// a will store the minimum value.
// b will store the maximum value.
```

**Bonus (How to Swap Number in C Language)**

```
void swap(int *a,int *b) {
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

Comment: `swap` exists in C++, but not in C, and cannot be implemented in C in a way that allows you to call it the way you do. But if this is meant to be pseudo-code, it's fine, in that case it would just help to point out that you realise that bits are missing.

Comment: yes, I know. I assume he can write swap(a,b) function easily. I will edit my original solution.

Comment: @algojava: The `swap(a, b)` is doable by C11 generic macros (though I agree it's not as elegant `std::swap` from C++). For instance, you could define `#define swap(a, b) _Generic((a), int: swapi)(&a, &b)`, where `swapi` is essentially the same as your `swap`. See https://godbolt.org/g/SFMdps.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4;
  
     printf("enter the numbers: ");
     scanf("%d %d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4);

     int large1 = num1, low1 = num2, low = num3, large = num4;
     if (num1 <= num2) {
         large1 = num2;
         low1 = num1;
     }
     if (num3 >= num4) {
         large = num3;
         low = num4;
     }
     if (large < large) {
         large = large1;
     }
     if (low > low1) {
         low = low1;
     }
     printf("%d\n", large);
     printf("%d\n", low);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_of_four(int a,int b, int c, int d)
{
    int max=0;
    max = (a > b ? (a > c ? (a > d ?   a :  d) :  (c > d ? c : d) ) : (b > c ? (b > d ? b : d>c? d : c ) : c>d? c : d)) ;

   return max;
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use of the ternary operator seems clearly off topic. Furthermore you only compute the max, not the min.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution with a single `if` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
  
    printf("enter the numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4) {
        int lo1 = a * (a <= b) + (a > b) * b;
        int hi1 = a * (a >= b) + (a < b) * b;
        int lo2 = c * (c <= d) + (c > d) * d;
        int hi2 = c * (c >= d) + (c < d) * d;
        int lo = lo1 * (lo1 <= lo2) + (lo1 > lo2) * lo2;
        int hi = hi1 * (hi1 >= hi2) + (hi1 < hi2) * hi2;
        printf("%d %d\n", hi, lo);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

its a very creative question. I have solved your problem using only two if statements.

```
int a = 22, b = 25, c = 100, d = 4;
        int max = 0, min = 0;
        if ((a > b ? (a > c ? (a > d ? max = a : max = d) : max = c) : (b > c ? (b > d ? max = b : max = d) : max = c)) == 1)
        {
              //Control never goes inside this loop
        }
        else if ((a < b ? (a < c ? (a < d ? min= a : min= d) : min= c) : (b < c ? (b < d ? min = b : min = d) : min = c)) == 1)
        {
             //Control never goes inside this loop
        }
        printf("Maximum Value is:%d and Minimum Value is: %d", max, min);//at this statement max and min will have appropriate values
```

Comment: `?:` is syntactic sugar for `if`/`else`.

Comment: It may be the same but they come under different classification in C ."?:" is a conditional operator and "if else" is a statement. And it was told not to use if statements more than 4 times. It didn.t mention that we cant use condtional operators. You better check your facts before rating negative to anyone.